# Redirecting One SiteCollection to Another Sitecollection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a root site collection with following http://sp.domain.com

I want to auto redirect all users who browse to the root site collection to another site collection with this http://sp.domain.com/test1 so that nobody can use root site collection.

Note: I don't want to Add content editor web part method adding script to web-part What can be the best solution.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved with [HTTP Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525695%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in [IIS](http://www.iis.net/) using [IIS URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). This module allows to create various rule actions including *redirect* and *request abort*.
It's probably  the most flexible and advanced way to configure the redirection.

### Configuration

First of all,  install [IIS URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Then you could configure Rule that redirect from a root site to a another site collection  in URL Rewrite as shown below
[image]